# Why these variances are calculated differently?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, linear-regression

I'm studying by this book [Data Analysis and Graphics Using R: An Example-Based Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521762936) and on chapter 5, page 150 they wrote:

> There are two types of predictions: prediction of points on the line, and prediction of a new data value. The SE estimates of predictions for new data values take account both of uncertainty in the line and of the variation of individual points about the line.

see this picture:

[image]

The point $(x,\hat Y)$ is the point on the line and $x^*$ is the new data I want to predict. Note the only difference between the points $(x,\hat Y)$ and $(x^*,Yˆ*)$ is the former the true true response $Y$ is given.

Following the book, in order to get the variance of the points when you know the true response $Y$, we only need to calculate the variance of the line, i.e., $\mathbb V(\beta_0 +\beta_1X_i)$ and when we don't know the true response, the variance is the variance of the line plus the variance of the noise $\epsilon_i$.

Could someone give me a formal or intuitive explanation why we don't need to take into account the variance of the noise in the first case? For me, the point I want to predict should be in the region of the possible lines plus the noise in both cases.

In another words, I don't understand why I don't need the noise counting for the variance when I have the true response $Y$. This noise $Y-\hat Y$ is for this specific line, but the lines are random, for every new line we will have another different $\epsilon$ like in the second case.

Comment: Yes you can have noise in $x$ too.  It leads to a different estimator.

Comment: You seem to be confusing estimation of your parameters with the prediction of a new observation. If $x^*=x$ and you still wanted to estimate an expected observation, you'd also have to incorporate the $\epsilon_i$. Basically, the extra $\epsilon_i$ is just the addition of the noise inherent in making a new observation. I don't know what you mean by the variance when you know the true response (at that point, they're just numbers, they don't have any variance), but if you mean the variance of, say, the *estimator* of the slope or something like that, then yeah, that doesn't have any extra

Comment: $epsilon_i$'s in it, since no new observation is adding randomness to what you're seeing. Heuristically speaking at least. Note that the noise of your initial observation *do* play a role in estimating the variance of your slope and intercept parameters, though.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou you're right, I confused the estimation of the parameters of the line with the estimation of the new points. I should have read this part in a more careful way. Thank you very much!